# Can I create a chat room for 3 different clients for Gtalk service?

Tags: macos, chat, adium

I'm using Adium on my Mac and I wish to communicate with several people. My friend on Linux uses Pidgin. Another friend is using Gtalk client and all using gtalk service. It's possible to create a chatroom to contain these clients similar to how Skype does group room chat?

Answer (score 1):

In Adium:

- Right click on one of the contacts, and use "Initiate Multiuser Chat with (name)@gmail.com"
- You should now join a group chat yourself, and an invitation will be send to that contact.
- Right click on the other contact, and select "Invite to Chat" → (The name of the private chat you created).
- Now the other contact gets an invitation they should accept.